# Is there a package in R that mimics KEDRO as a modular collaborative framework for development?

Tags: r, frameworks, collaboration, kedro

I currently work with Kedro (from quantum black https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/01_introduction/01_introduction.html) as a framework for deployment oriented framework to code collaboratively. It is a great framework to develop machine learning in a team.

I am looking for an R equivalent.

My main issue is that I have teams of data scientists that develop in R, but each team is developing in different formats.

I wanted to make them follow a common framework to develop deployment ready R code, easy to work on in 2 or 3-people teams.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

member of the Kedro team here. We've heard good things about the [Targets](https://github.com/ropensci/targets) library doing similar things in the R world.

It would be remiss for me to not try and covert you and your team to the dark side too :)

Before Kedro our teams internally were writing a mix of Python, SQL, Scala and R. Part of the drive to write the framework was to get our teams internally speaking the same language. Python felt like the best compromise available at the time and I'd argue this still holds. We also had trouble productionising R projects and felt Python is more manageable in that respect.

Whilst not officially documented - I've also seen some people on the Kedro [Discord play with r2py](https://discord.com/channels/778216384475693066/778998585454755870/901111920290070588) so that they can use specific R functionality within their Python pipelines.

Comment: I agree with all your comments. However, there some R developments, mainly in the statistical academic world, that açready come ready in R, so I like to keep the teams diverse in that sense. But, again, I agree with you, thats why I use Kedro with everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

Not on a very prominent scale as kedro but i can think of the below :

1. Local project of a R Expert : https://github.com/Jeniffen/projectr
2. Pipeliner on Tidyverse : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pipeliner/index.html

Comment: Maybe Tidymodels could accomplish this task. https://www.tidymodels.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar position (team using kedro), I found [mage](https://www.mage.ai/) which allows you to declare pipelines in a similar fashion that include R, Python, and SQL blocks.